# Realtime Database show if data is still hasn't been uploaded

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

so I'm working with realtime database and I'm trying to make a chat app for practice.

I want to add the message to my list then let the message item inside the list upload the message to the server, I'm also showing an indicator that tells the user if the message is being uploaded, there are other approaches to apply this but I want to go with this one, anyways.

there isn't any problem when there is an internet connection. the problem is when there isn't any internet connection, the message is added to the list and the indicator appears, when the internet connection returns everything works fine still.

but if I send a message (while offline) and then leave the chat room and return to the chat room, the messages will get loaded and the indicator won't appear altho it isn't uploaded to the server (the data is cached now).

I want to find a way to tell if the data has been uploaded or not? I don't want to check the server to see if the node exists, I can't do that to every message it will cost too much, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable disk persistence, Firebase keeps all of its *pending writes* in its disk cache. When the app restarts, it reads those pending writes and starts trying them. This is usually the right behavior for your users.

Unfortunately there is no built-in way to persist completion handlers for the Realtime Database. So upon a restart it becomes impossible for you to detect when the pending writes have been committed on the server.

So this typically means that you need to do something custom to detect the situation, and will have to determine for yourself whether the use-case is worth the effort.

If your messages are in some way ordered/timestamped (for example, if you add them by calling `push()`) you can keep track of what the last message is for which you received a confirmation from the server. That way you will know when the client restarts, which messages may not have been sent to the server yet.

Your `onDataChange` or `onChildAdded` *will* be called for those unconfirmed message straight away though when your app restarts, so you'll need an additional mechanism to detect when those unconfirmed messages are written on the server.

The best approach I know if is to write a "dummy" message when the app starts. Since the pending writes are treated as a first-in-first-out queue, your new dummy message write will be sent to the server after all the pending writes from the previous run. So when your completion handler gets called for this dummy message, you can be sure that all messages before it have also been committed (or rejected in case they violate your security rules).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you've confirmed my thoughts... sadly I don't think it is worth the struggle of making it work, I reported a ticket and hopefully, they'll add it as a new feature, they just need to add a value to the snapshots which will be modified to true when the server finishes writing the data.

Comment: If you want that type of delivery information, consider using Cloud Firestore, which adds precisely that in its `SnapshotMetadata.hasPendingWrites()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata

Comment: Yes, I started switching to firestore but I'm not sure if it will compatible with what I want to achieve, thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase cloud functions fires an onFinalize event when a file has been uploaded to the storage. So you could probably write a cloud function like this.

```
exports.uploadedServer = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
  const filename = object.name
  //mark this filename or filekey as upload complete
  return
})
```

You should be able to find more explanation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events).

Comment: I don't think the question is about uploading files to Cloud Storage to Firebase, is it? As far as I can read it's purely about detecting whether a message has been committed to the server with Realtime Database.

Comment: Yes @FrankvanPuffelen, I want to know if a the snapshot that is stored locally or has been uploaded to the server? or is it waiting to be uploaded?